# Windows Security PopUp in Microsoft Edge automatize with python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver, jupyter-notebook, microsoft-edge

I am trying to automatize in python a report downloading task I have in Microsoft Edge. Have been using Selenium and "Autoit" for it but once I load the webpage I need to access, I get this Windows Security Popup to introduce my credentials.
I tried different methods but no success at all because i cannot retrieve the element main Ids which are like this ones:

```
AutomationElement
  General Accessibility
    AccessKey:  ""
    AcceleratorKey: ""
    IsKeyboardFocusable:    "True"
    LabeledBy:  "(null)"
    HelpText:   ""

  State
    IsEnabled:  "True"
    HasKeyboardFocus:   "False"

  Identification
    ClassName:  "TextBox"
    ControlType:    "ControlType.Edit"
    Culture:    "es-ES"
    AutomationId:   "EditField_1"
    LocalizedControlType:   "editar"
    Name:   "Nombre de usuario"
    ProcessId:  "21124 (CredentialUIBroker)"
    RuntimeId:  "42 1115840 4 11"
    IsPassword: "False"
    IsControlElement:   "True"
    IsContentElement:   "True"

  Visibility
    BoundingRectangle:  "(498, 451, 444, 47)"
    ClickablePoint: "720,475"
    IsOffscreen:    "False"

ControlPatterns
  ScrollItem

  Text
    DocumentRange
      Text: ""
      Length:   "0"
      Bounding Rectangles:  "(511, 462, 2, 28)"
      AnimationStyleAttribute:  "None"
      BackgroundColorAttribute: "16777215"
      BulletStyleAttribute: "None"
      CapStyleAttribute:    "None"
      CultureAttribute: "es-ES"
      FontNameAttribute:    "Segoe UI"
      FontSizeAttribute:    "10.5"
      FontWeightAttribute:  "400"
      ForegroundColorAttribute: "0"
      HorizontalTextAlignmentAttribute: "Left"
      IndentationFirstLineAttribute:    "0"
      IndentationLeadingAttribute:  "0"
      IndentationTrailingAttribute: "0"
      IsHiddenAttribute:    "False"
      IsItalicAttribute:    "False"
      IsReadOnlyAttribute:  "False"
      IsSubscriptAttribute: "False"
      IsSuperscriptAttribute:   "False"
      MarginBottomAttribute:    "(not supported)"
      MarginLeadingAttribute:   "(not supported)"
      MarginTopAttribute:   "(not supported)"
      MarginTrailingAttribute:  "(not supported)"
      OutlineStylesAttribute:   "None"
      OverlineColorAttribute:   "(not supported)"
      OverlineStyleAttribute:   "(not supported)"
      StrikethroughColorAttribute:  "(not supported)"
      StrikethroughStyleAttribute:  "None"
      TabsAttribute:    "36"
      TextFlowDirectionsAttribute:  "Default"
      UnderlineColorAttribute:  "(not supported)"
      UnderlineStyleAttribute:  "None"

  Value
    Value:  ""
    IsReadOnly: "False"
```

```
try:
    # Activate the Windows Security window
    autoit.WinActivate("Seguridad de Windows")

    # Set focus on the text box and type the desired text
    #autoit.ControlClick("Seguridad de Windows", "", "PlaceholderTextContentPresenter")
    #autoit.ControlSetText("Seguridad de Windows", "", "PlaceholderTextContentPresenter", "KerryJones")

    # Click the accept button
    autoit.ControlClick("Seguridad de Windows", "", "Cancelar")
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
```